# Diffrence between two datetime in desire format using angular js

Tags: angularjs, datetime

How to check diffrence between two datetime in desire format using angular js.

```
var ms = moment($scope.date1,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").diff(moment($scope.date2,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
            var d = moment.duration(ms);
            var s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + moment.utc(ms).format(":mm:ss");
            console.log("Date diff.........",s);
```

output:

```
date1........ 2017-12-26 16:20:00
date2........ 2017-12-26 15:10:38
Diff- 01:10 
(If should ignore date because there is not date diffrence and if date diffrence is there then it show display like 03:10:05)

Diff (In format- DD-HH-MM)
DD-Days
HH-Hours
MM-Minutes
```

Tried Code:

```
$scope.cdate = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
console.log("current time........",$scope.cdate);

                     $scope.Mydata=Data.timestamp;  //I am Getting this data from response

                        this.getDateDiff = function(cdate, Mydata) {
                        let d1 = new Date($scope.cdate);
                        let d2 = new Date($scope.Mydata);
                        let diff = Math.abs(d1.getTime() - d2.getTime());
                        let diffDate = new Date(0, 0, 0);
                            diffDate.setMilliseconds(diff);
                        let dayMills = ((60**2) * 24) * 1000;
                        let days = Math.round(diff / dayMills);

                            function formatNumberString(number) {
                                return ('0' + number).slice(-2);
                                    }
                            return  {
                                    days: formatNumberString(days),
                                    hours: formatNumberString(diffDate.getHours()),
                                    minutes: formatNumberString(diffDate.getMinutes()),
                                    seconds: formatNumberString(diffDate.getSeconds())
                                    }
                        }
                        $scope.dateDiff = this.getDateDiff($scope.cdate, $scope.Mydata);
                        console.log("days diff.........",$scope.dateDiff);
```

Output:

Input:
current time- 2017-12-29 10:19:41
Mydata- 2017-02-09 18:16:38

result is coming wrong-
{days: "23", hours: "16", minutes: "03", seconds: "03"}

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using native JavaScript.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.date1 = "2017-12-26 16:20:00";
  $scope.date2 = "2017-12-26 15:10:38"

  this.getDateDiff = function(date1, date2) {
    let d1 = new Date(date1);
    let d2 = new Date(date2);
    let diff = Math.abs(d1.getTime() - d2.getTime());
    let diffDate = new Date(0, 0, 0);
    diffDate.setMilliseconds(diff);
    let dayMills = ((60**2) * 24) * 1000;
    let days = Math.round(diff / dayMills);

    function formatNumberString(number) {
      return ('0' + number).slice(-2);
    }
    return {
      days: formatNumberString(days),
      hours: formatNumberString(diffDate.getHours()),
      minutes: formatNumberString(diffDate.getMinutes()),
      seconds: formatNumberString(diffDate.getSeconds())
    }
  }
  $scope.dateDiff = this.getDateDiff($scope.date1, $scope.date2);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>date1...... {{date1}}</div>
    <div>date2...... {{date2}}</div>
    <div>
      <span>Diff - </span>
      <span ng-if="dateDiff.days > 0">{{dateDiff.days}} : </span>
      <span>{{ dateDiff.hours }} : </span>
      <span>{{ dateDiff.minutes }}</span>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: any other simple way to do that... I am displaying like +$scope.dateDiff.days+ this is giving error..

Comment: @TB.M are you able to Run code snippet correctly? Can you post more of your code either here or on plunker?

Answer (score -1):

See if this works for you.

your controller file-

```
$scope.date1 = "2017-12-26 16:20:00";
$scope.date2 = "2017-12-26 15:10:38";

var diff = moment.utc(date1, "yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").diff(moment.utc(date2, "yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"), 'minutes');
var days=diff/(24*60);
var hours=diff/60;
var minutes=diff%60;
$scope.arr = [];
if(parseInt(days)){
  arr.push(parseInt(days));
}
if(parseInt(hours)){
  arr.push(('0'+hours).substring(-1, 2));
}
if(minutes){
  arr.push(('0'+minutes).substring(-1, 2));
}
console.log(arr.join(':'));
```

Your html file-

```
...
<div>{{arr.join(':')}}</div>
...
```